# Smoothing grouped data using group_by and smooth function from stats package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, smoothing

I am trying to smooth some columns in a tibble object. I am using a data similiar to the one bellow.

```
rep <- tibble(source = rep(1:5, each = 921),
              V1 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
              V2 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
              V3 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
              V4 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
              V5 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2)) %>% 
        group_by(source) %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(V1:V5), smooth, kind = "3RS3R")
```

The problem is: everytime I run the code, R gives me the followin error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `V1`.
x Input `V1` must return compatible vectors across groups
i Input `V1` is `(function (x, kind = c("3RS3R", "3RSS", "3RSR", "3R", "3", "S"), ...`.
i Result type for group 1 (source = 1): <tukeysmooth>.
i Result type for group 3 (source = 3): <tukeysmooth>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

According to the error message, my code is returning incompatible vectors across groups, but at the end of the message it's possible to see that it's returning the same type os vectors (`<tukeysmooth>`). How can I use smooth across this grouped data in those five columns? I have tried different dplyr verbs and formats of tibble, all of them always give me this error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert output from `smooth` to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
tibble(source = rep(1:5, each = 921),
       V1 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
       V2 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
       V3 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
       V4 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2),
       V5 = rnorm(4605, mean = 3, sd = 0.2)) %>% 
  group_by(source) %>% 
  mutate(across(V1:V5, ~as.numeric(smooth(., kind = "3RS3R")))) %>%
  ungroup

#   source    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1  2.89  3.04  2.91  3.14  2.88
# 2      1  2.95  3.06  2.91  3.14  2.91
# 3      1  3.01  3.07  3.05  3.08  3.10
# 4      1  3.03  3.07  3.05  3.07  3.11
# 5      1  3.03  2.98  3.05  3.07  3.11
# 6      1  3.03  2.84  3.05  3.00  3.04
# 7      1  3.03  2.77  2.89  2.93  2.77
# 8      1  2.91  2.77  2.70  2.93  2.70
# 9      1  2.91  2.91  2.70  2.93  2.70
#10      1  2.91  3.08  2.71  2.93  2.70
# … with 4,595 more rows
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! But I have a question: why does this work? Why is needed to convert to numeric?

Comment: Because `smooth` returns output of class "tukeysmooth" with some additional information which the tibble does not understand how to store in a column. By converting to numeric we keep only the numeric part of the output, turn it into class numeric which can be stored in tibble.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you so much!